# Tipo columna blob no registra con tipo "b"

Tags: php, mysqli, inyección-sql

Al intentar ingresar un texto de comentarios en una columna tipo blob, que en la codificación anti-inyeccion-sql (`mysqli_stmt_bind_param`) tiene una "b", no registra el texto.

```
($sentencia = $enlace->prepare("INSERT INTO tabla (nombre, direccion, ciudad, comentarios) values (?,?,?,?)"));

$sentencia->bind_param("sssb", $nombre, $direccion, $ciudad, $comentarios); 

$sentencia->execute();
```

He cambiado la codificación a una "s" y ahora graba el texto, ¿he hecho bien?.

Comment: Hola @Joan, sería de gran ayuda que adjuntases el código que estás probando para analizar mejor el caso.

Comment: En "Ayuda de Markdown" pone que 2 espacios al final de linea equivalen a un salto de linea <br />. Yo lo hago y no fuciona.  

($sentencia = $enlace->prepare("INSERT INTO tabla (nombre, direccion, ciudad, comentarios) values (?,?,?,?)"))   

$sentencia->bind_param("sssb", $nombre, $direccion, $ciudad, $comentarios)  

$sentencia->execute()

Comment: El código tienes que ponerlo en el primer mensaje, el de arriba del todo.... edita ese y coloca el código ahí. Porque estos comentarios son más bien para escribir pocas frases y no guardan el sangrado.

Answer (score 0):

Ya tengo respuesta de otro foro.

No hará daño, pero si es texto mejor definir el campo como text o longtext, el tipo blob es más para guardar archivos (p.e. imágenes) en la bbdd y el funcionamiento al leer / escribir datos binarios es algo especial:
https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/entry/php_s_mysqli_extension_storing

Entonces voy a modificar el tipo de la columna a text o longtext.

Saludos